# Fetch Record according to occurence in like query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am using a simple my-sql LIKE query... My column records are "Strong, True, Trap, Strip" so on.

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%tr%'".
```

Like this. I simply want to fetch the records according to its occuring position. Like Trap, True, Strip, Strong. Is it possible to manipulate query according to occurence in like.

Comment: by occurence what do u mean??

Comment: Can you post some example data and desired output? Because as of right now, this makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: i think u want to display results in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean order the results based on the location of your search string? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%tr%' ORDER BY LOCATE('tr', name) ASC
```

Comment: How much hit will it make on server ?? Is it will be slow comparison to other.

Comment: I don't imagine it would be any more intensive than the LIKE part of the query. Also, the LOCATE function would only be applied to the matching results, so it shouldn't be bad at all.

Comment: Can you give me reference to this keyword of mysql

Comment: [LOCATE() in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..and get records according to you.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%tr%' ORDER BY LOCATE('tr', name),name ASC
```